# How can I pass variables in AngularJS from one controller to next in ASP MVC setup?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Say for example, under `Views/Index.cshtml`, I have a form with a few inputs, once filled out and submitted, goes through a function in the controller js file to then `window.location.pathname` redirect to another page. This next page is associated with another controller/js file.

How would I pass a couple variables over from one to the other?

I've tried doing it this way and it doesn't work:

**First Try**

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<html ng-app="MIScheduler">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()

        // AngularJS scripts
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
<input ng-model="userID" name="userID" />
<input ng-model="userEmail" name="userEmail" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />

@section scripts {
    <script src="HomeController.js"></script>
}
```

`HomeController.js`:

```
var CID = null;
var Email = null;

$scope.submit = function() {
    CID = $scope.userID;
    Email = $scope.userEmail;
    window.location.pathname = 'Home/OtherPage';
};
```

Then when redirects to `OtherPage.cshtml`:

```
{{cid}}
{{email}}

@section scripts {
    <script src="OtherPageController.js"></script>
}
```

Doesn't output anything if my `OtherPageController.js`:

```
$scope.cid = CID;
$scope.email = Email;
```

I've also tried implementing a service in `app.js` and passing in the service to both controllers, but nothing outputs this way as well.

**Second Try**

Here's my second approach I tried: `app.js`:

```
angular.module('moveinScheduler', [])
    .service('ShareUserInfo', function () {
        LData = {
            cid: '',
            email: ''
        }

        return {
            getValues: function () {
                return LData;
            },
            setValues: function (cid, email) {
                LData.cid = cid;
                LData.email = email;
            }
        };
    });
```

`Index.cshtml` is same as above. `HomeController.cshtml`:

```
var CID = null;
var Email = null;

$scope.submit = function() {
    ShareUserInfo.setValues(d.data.CID, d.data.Email);
    window.location.pathname = 'Home/OtherPage';
};
```

`OtherPageController.js`:

```
$scope.values = ShareUserInfo.getValues();
```

`OtherPage.cshtml`:

```
{{values}}
```

Nothing is being output. Keep in mind for both of the controllers, I'm passing in `ShareUserInfo` into the function as a service extension.

Any ideas on what's wrong? Why my values aren't being stored/passed around?

Comment: so you do not have a single page app? Could you perhaps pass the variable in the querystring to the othersPage.html

Comment: @Maccurt I'm trying to avoid the querystring option with regards to the email that's passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data in the [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

HomeController.js:

```
angular.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        var obj = {
            cid: $scope.userID,
            email: $scope.userEmail
        };
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(obj));
        // Make your redirect
    };
});
```

PageController.js:

```
angular.controller('PageController', function($scope) {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

    console.log('data: ', data);
});
```

Comment: The use of `['ngStrorage']` needs to be placed in all of the js files including `app.js` right?

Comment: I have removed dependency on `ngStorage` to make it easier.. Now you can save data directly in `localStorage`.

Comment: I have one problem, I did exactly as your code states above. In `HomeController.js`, I get an error once I execute function which is _$localStorage is not defined_. But if I put `$localStorage` into `...('HomeController', function ($scope, $localStorage)..` the code breaks and I get _Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider_

Comment: Give a try to the updated the response please.. The reason you are getting that errors is because you have to first install the module `ngStorage` https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage and Require ngStorage and Inject the Services in the controllers..

Comment: This is so weird. The console is empty. In my submit function, the way I redirect to the other page is this: `window.location.pathname = 'Home/OtherPage';` (I have this at the end of the submit function), is this why it's not showing?

Comment: The idea is the same: Store your `data` in localStorage to make it available for multiple views. You have to execute: `localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(obj));` before redirect..

Comment: Than in your new page you have to execute: `var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));`

Comment: Everything I have in my code is exactly the same as what you've given me as an example. The `console.log` won't print anything to console once the page redirects, and the variables are null/nonexistant on the redirect page, I can edit my question and put this in as a Third Attempt. If I get to ther second redirected page and hit refresh, then the console outputs that both variables are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using a Single Page Application, and you are avoiding the use of querystring, you can use a $http.post, and pass a view model object to your OtherPageController.  In the OtherPageController, implement an [HttpPost] action method that takes the view model object passed in from your $http.post call.